# I wants to create versioning of angular 4 build --prod--aot

Tags: angular

I wants to create versioning of very angular 4 build (ng buid --prod--aot).i have created many of build but due to browser cache changes are not reflecting we need to hard reload with empty cache.

anyone can tell me how to clear cache

thanks

Comment: one more issue is coming Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.5f6d6a7d7feb0c3e5505.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
   at polyfills.5f6d6a7d7feb0c3e5505.bundle.js:1
asdas.auperator.net/:46

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `output-hashing` as true when you are building using CLI

```
ng build --aot --output-hashing=true
```

This will add a hash value to each file name and which is unique for every build

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue here... building with -aot (dev) works fine. Prod compiles without complaint but when loading the app on the browser, it returns the following errors:

polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1
85d3367f26ac4251.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.dfb485d3367f26ac4251.bundle.js:1

Comment: i guess there are some issues in the code, please check it